# Passing arguments stored in a file when running projects in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line-arguments

My problem is that I can't remember how I can pass the arguments when running a project in netbeans. There is not enough documentation on web if anybody could help it would be highly appreciated.

Here is what I know, you can change the run configurations under run> Set Project Configuration >customize there there is a entry space where you can enter the arguments to be passed.

I have a file called **"AsciiShop.java"** which to be runned and I need to pass the arguments stored in a file called **"asciishop-A04-PP.i1"**. When I am using terminal or cmd.exe I can run the program with

**java AsciiShop < asciishop-A04-PP.i1**

and it works perfect. I want to be able to the same on netbeans. I have placed the file in the default working directory which contains src and bin folders.
What should I write in the arguments entry field on the project configurations window, so that it works same like **java AsciiShop < asciishop-A04-PP.i1**

Comment: Arguments don't go in a file normally.  Also, in your case, `asciishop-A04-PP.i1` is a pipe, not an argument.

Comment: -1 for drive-by linking in chat.

Comment: Correction: it's a _stream_, not a pipe.

Comment: Well you can store the arguments in a file and pass it to the program in runtime. I am wondering how did you come to the conclusion that I am assuming asciishop-A04-PP.i1 is an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the "Run" menu and select "Project Configurations" from the drop down you will see a secondary drop down that has the default configuration and a "Customize" option.  Select the "Customize" options and you can specify arguments to pass in there.

Comment: I tried to specify it that I know where to pass the arguments but I dont know how to pass them as a file. But thanks for the try my question remains unanswered unfortunately

Comment: My apologizes, I misunderstood the question.  I do not think that is possible.  I tried several tricks in the arguments field to try and force it to evaluate the file as a file instead of an argument with no luck(backtics, cat, <, etc). I think it doesn't output it to a shell so it doesn't evaluate the arguments as anything but arguments.

Comment: I have made it happen in a school project last year but I can't remember it anymore. I will post it here if I manage it to find it before someone else. Thanks for your effort though.